# Integral involving Airy functions and exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, airy-functions

I'm struggling calculating the following integral:

$$\int_ {-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{Ai}(x)~\operatorname{Ai}(x-2it) e^{2(x-it)} dx $$
Where x is a complex number. I'm studying "Airy Functions and Applications to Physics" (Soares and Valee) but I cannot figure it out. Could anyone help me?

Comment: If $x$ is complex, shouldn't you specify the contour of integration?

Comment: Answer is : $$\frac{e^{\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{2}{3}}}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$$ :)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thank you very much! Can I have the proof?

Comment: Nope.I used the **Mathematica**

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk could you please post the commands that you used?

Comment: On **Mathematica 12.3.0**  Code:`Integrate[
 Integrate[
  AiryAi[x]*1/(2 Pi)*Exp[(I a^3)/3 + 2 a t + I a x]*
   Exp[2 (x - I t)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {t \[Element] Reals, Im[a] < 2}], {a, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]` and $$\text{Ai}(x-2 i t)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(\frac{i a^3}{3}+2 a t+i a x\right)}{2 \pi } \,
   da$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thank you, you are the best! Would you mind calculating this [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323733/integral-involving-airy-functions-and-exponential-function) too?