# Integral involving Airy functions and exponential function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, exponential-function, infinity, airy-functions

Has anyone any idea about the following integral:

$$\int_ {-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{Ai}(x)~\operatorname{Ai}(x-2it) e^{2(x-it-0.5t^2)} dx $$
Where x is a complex number. I'm studying "Airy Functions and Applications to Physics" (Soares and Valee) but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Lemma 2.6 here could help I think
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101201.pdf

Comment: $$\frac{e^{\frac{2}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$$